# Como cortar una cadena en una N cantidad de veces

Tags: c#

```
string cadena = "TIssChecklistBox-29753-8-Head Trauma/Concussion - details 
below";
```

y debo cortar la misma con el metodo split

```
var arr = cadena.Split('-');
```

usando el guion pero quisiera que solo hiciera split en las 3 primeras apariciones del guion de tal forma que me quedara todo lo despues del Head en una sola posicion.
es esto posible?

Comment: si.. leyendo el manual ;) [aca](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_String___System_Int32_System_StringSplitOptions_)

Comment: pero si ya lo tienes , que importa que el split lo haga, concatenas las posiciones [3] en adelante!

Comment: lo que hace falta es que me quede esto Head Trauma/Concussion - details 
below en una sola posicion, cuando split corta por el guion me separa esta cadena en 2 porque tiene el guion pero deberia estar en una sola

Comment: @JackNavaRow por qué habríamos de hacer concatenación de n elementos. Para el caso expuesto sabemos que es uno, pero que pasaría si hay mas de un guion en lo que supongo es la descripción del registro? y si no tiene? En fin, para qué hacer toda una rutina, si el mismo Split lo puede resolver..

Comment: @KodiakMx El resultado sería el mismo.. hay demasiadas maneras de resolver un problema, lo que plantea es totalmente válido..

Comment: otra solucion , ejecuta dos split uno con `" - "` fijate los espacio y la posicion [0] otro split `"-"`

Answer (score 4):

También a mi me confundió.. Para utilizar el split con más de un parámetro, el primer parámetro debe de ser un arreglo de caracteres.

```
var arr = cadena.Split(new char[] { '-' }, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Si sólo quieres los tres primeros elementos, pues sólo extrae los tres primeros:

```
var resultado = new List<String>();

int begin = 0, end = cadena.IndexOf('-');

// Saltamos de guion en guion, pero sólo para los tres primeros.
for (int token = 0; token < 3; ++token)
//                          ^ <--- No pases de tres!
{
    resultado.Add(cadena.Substring(begin, end - begin));
    begin = end + 1;
    end = cadena.IndexOf('-', begin);
}
// Guardamos el resto de la cadena, del tercer guion en adelante.
resultado.Add(cadena.Substring(begin));
```